# How to know if rules are fulfilled on a specific field with vuetify

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I use vuetify and I have rules on a phone field :

```
 rules: {
                    required: value => !!value || 'please fill it',
                    counter: value => value.length <= 12 && value.length > 9 || 'please fill it',
                    digits: value => {
                        const pattern = /^\d+$/
                        return pattern.test(value) || 'only digits'
                    }
                },
```

and it works, but now I need to show a specific button on my form if all rules on *phone field* are fulfilled, is there an option to use the rules in this way? if yes then how? if no so I guess i'll have to write a function that checks all these rules again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a quick example in CodeSandbox to show you one way you could achieve your goal. Basically, you can use the property v-model on your form element to link your "state" (valid or not) and then use it where you need to hide/show or disable/enable elements. Take a look at the App.vue file in the example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-forked-uzp6h0?from-embed=&file=/src/App.vue